# (K)ubuntu 18.04 - PulseAudio - Set Bluetooth Headphones As Default

Tags: sound, kubuntu, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I have a set of Bluetooth headphones connected to my XPS 13 laptop:

[Bluetooth devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2UCa.png)

They connect and sound fine, but the audio mixer seems to keep wanting to switch things back to the built in speakers constantly.

[PulseAudio Mixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us4Ts.png)

I can then change the audio source to the headphones:

[Selecting Headphones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3D4N.png)

And all is well, until I pause the video long enough for (I think) Chrome to close the audio channel. Once it's re-opened it will have the built in speakers selected again, and I have to re-open the PulseAudio Mixer to switch the output again.

This happens for any new audio sources as well. Is there any way I can force the MDX headphones to be the output device for ALL audio, as long as they're connected?

It's extremely difficult on some applications like Telegram, when I play a video from there it fullscreens automatically (which is frustrating for it's own reasons) and any attempt to switch to the PulseAudio Mixer closes the video, which closes the audio channel, which means I can't switch it anyways.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with my bluetooth headphones. In my case the problem started many months after the installation of Kubuntu 18.04 so I think an update was the cause.

No matter how many times I set the bluetooth device as default in the audio control it didn't matter.

The solution for me came when I changed the settings in 
**System Settings > Multimedia > Audio and Video > Device Preference (Tab)**
for Audio Playback I set the headphones as the most preferred.

[image: settings]

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was driving me nuts, as changing the device priorities did not get chrome, specifically to stop playing out my laptop speakers (also an XPS 13, incidentally).

The solution was weirdly simple, though not obvious at all. When audio is playing, and you can see the "Chromium" stream in the Applications tab, click and drag the icon to the preferred device (the applications tab should switch back to "Devices" as you move your mouse).

I haven't tested thoroughly, but this seems to persist after restarting chrome.

I have the KDE bionic-backports ppa enabled, and I suspect it has something to do with these audio issues.